# Django: Dealing with Username Changes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

This might be a silly question, but I thought I'd ask before I continue doing anything.

Assume I have two models: the first, some `User` model, and the second an `ImgUpload` model which captures the username automatically as the form is submitted and stores it in the database.

If I end up updating a username (let's say **User1** -> **User2**) or any other field from the `User` model, will the `ImgUpload` model automatically capture this change or do I need some sort of way to handle this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Django is perfectly capable of doing that for you so no worries.

Comment: to clarify, Django will only autoupdate those fields that span models such as ForeignKey and so on. Let me know if you need a sample code for this.

Comment: Understood, something like so? `username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfileModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: correct, that should do it.